# Using an existing connection string in an Entity Framework Database first entity connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have introduced Entity Framework Database first into an existing project which already has connection strings in the web.config file.

So I have two connection strings in the web config that both refer to the same database:

```
<add name="uatConnection" connectionString="Data Source=172.16.0.2;Initial      Catalog=MyDatabaseUat;Persist Security Info=True;User     ID=MyDatabaseUserId;Password=MyDatabasePassword;Connect Timeout=600"     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="MyDatabaseUatEntities"  connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyWebsite.csdl|res://*/Models.MyWebsite.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyWebsite.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=172.16.0.2;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseUat;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyDatabaseUserId;Password=MyDatabasePassword;Connect Timeout=600&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

How can I change the second one to refer to the first one?

Can I do this?

Rather than just shooting in the dark, I wonder if anyone knows the correct way of dealing with this situation in practice.

Comment: why do you need to do that?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you looking for, you want to use the Entity Framework (System.Data.EntityClient) instead of System.Data.SqlClient) ? You will have to change all the connection to the database in your code.

Comment: @Sampath - so that they stay in sync

Comment: You'd have to use the code-based [`EntityFrameworkConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to build your EF connection string based on the "regular" ADO.NET connection string. There's no mechanism in .NET config files to replace certains parts with other key's values